# Duplicate scanner band-aid for do-while? (Java)

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner, conditional-statements, do-while

So I'm a little confused as to why this is happening, here's my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    do
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a time in 24-hour notation: ");
        String time = in.nextLine();

        int colonIndex = time.indexOf(":");
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, colonIndex));
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(colonIndex + 1));

        boolean legalTime = ((hours < 24 && hours > 0) && (minutes < 60 && minutes >= 0));
        boolean addZero = minutes < 10;
        boolean pm = hours > 12;

        if(legalTime)
        {
            if(pm && addZero)
            {
                int newHour = hours - 12;
                System.out.printf("That is the same as"
                        + "\n%d:0%d PM\n", newHour, minutes);
            }
            else if(pm && !addZero)
            {
                hours = hours - 12;
                System.out.printf("That is the same as"
                        + "\n%d:%d PM\n", hours, minutes);
            }
            else if (!pm && addZero)
            {
                System.out.printf("That is the same as"
                        + "\n%d:0%d AM\n", hours, minutes);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf("That is the same as"
                        + "\n%d:%d AM\n", hours, minutes);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            if(!legalTime)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception: there is no such time as " + time);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()
                    + "\nAgain? (y/n)");
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println("Again? (y/n)");

    }while(Character.toUpperCase(kb.next().charAt(0)) == 'Y');

}
```

My code itself is not the issue, it's that the condition of a do-while loop only recognizes booleans outside of the do-while, which in my mind makes it quite frustrating to make the condition be affected by whatever is inside the block. What I want to do is make my code run, and then ask the user if they want to run it again, denoted by "y" or "n." I can't put

```
!time.charAt(0) == 'y'
```

As the condition because the string "time" is defined inside the do-while loop, so I made some weird band-aid by using one scanner just for the condition input before the do-while begins, and using another one inside the body. I know this is bad, but I can't think of a simple way to create a boolean for this condition that isn't inside the do-while loop, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a `boolean` before the loop instead of the extra `Scanner`, and update this `boolean` inside the loop:

```
boolean again = true;
do {
    ...
    System.out.println("Again? (y/n)");
    again = Character.toUpperCase(in.next().charAt(0)) == 'Y';
} while (again);
```